# Coded UI BrowserWindow casting to Selenium InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a CodedUI project in Visual studio along with Selenium web driver.

I have CodedUI's **BrowserWindow** and a Selenium's **InternetExplorerDriver**.
Is there any way to cast CodedUI's **BrowserWindow** to Selenium's **InternetExplorerDriver**?

Example like:

```
BrowserWindow browser = new BrowserWindow.Launch("http://abc.xyz");
IWebDriver driver = browser;
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, they are two entirely different things.

Comment: Yeah. I was guessing so.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do some activities using selenium browser and some with Codedui browser. Then Launch browser using selenium and use codedui browser to attach it.

example

**Selenium Browser**

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["iedriver_exe"]);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlLink);

**CodedUi Browser**
var browser = BrowserWindow.Locate("browsertitle");

Comment: Exactly !!
However i am wondering about Vice-Versa. **CodedUi Browser** to **CodedUi Browser**

Thanks